# ipad mini retina wrong screen resolution

Tags: ios, ipad, retina-display, ipad-mini

I can't take good results when I try to read resolution of my device.

Such code

```
 CGRect screenRect = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
     CGFloat screenWidth = screenRect.size.width;
     CGFloat screenHeight = screenRect.size.height;
     NSString* name = [self machineName];
```

gives

1024*768 and iPad4,5

machineName code:

```
#import <sys/utsname.h>
-(NSString*) machineName()
{
    struct utsname systemInfo;
    uname(&systemInfo);

    return [NSString stringWithCString:systemInfo.machine
                              encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
}
```

What am I doing wrong? I can't understand. It must be 2048*1536

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bound returns the screen dimensions in points.

You need to query `CGFloat scale = [[UIScreen mainScreen] scale];`

and multiply this by the width/height to get the pixel value

Comment: is this a feature of retina?

Comment: it is a UIScreen property. It will return 1.0f on a non retina and 2.0f on a retina

Answer (score 2):

Try this one to get screen resolution in points...

(1) Find the screen scale using below method

```
CGFloat screenScale = [[UIScreen mainScreen] scale];
```

This will give you the scale of the screen. For all iPhones and iPodTouches that do NOT have Retina Displays will return a 1.0f, while Retina Display devices will give a 2.0f.

Now if you want to get the pixel width & height of the iOS device screen you just need to do one simple thing.

(2) By multiplying by the screen's scale you get the actual pixel resolution.

```
CGSize screenSize = CGSizeMake([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width * screenScale, [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height * screenScale);
```

For more details read [this link](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/2DDrawing/Conceptual/DrawingPrintingiOS/GraphicsDrawingOverview/GraphicsDrawingOverview.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010156-CH14-SW7)